# How to enumerate rules from a validated viewmodel property (using knockout.validation)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

If I have a simple view model, with a validated property, e.g:

```
var viewModel = {
    myProperty: ko.observable().extend({ 
        email: true,
        required: true
    })
};
```

and a component that expects such a property:

```
<myComponent data-bind="params: { validatedProperty: myProperty }"></myComponent>
```

how can I determine which validation rules have been defined for `myProperty` from *within* the component code? i.e.

```
var ComponentViewModel = function(params) {
    // DOESN'T WORK: rules is always empty
    var firstRule = params.validatedProperty.rules[0];
};
return { viewModel: ComponentViewModel, template: htmlString};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rules` is an observable. Invoke it to get its contents:

```
var firstRule = params.validatedProperty.rules()[0];
```

Comment: Arggh. Thanks, that's it.